How can I improve the performance of a "cold" (first) run of this seemingly simple query?
I'm working on a specific query which has been slowing down an application for some time. The table in question has about 55 million rows.
A "cold" (first) run of this query usually takes about 30 seconds.
The database is an AWS RDS MySQL db.m6g.large instance. The disk is a 750GB gp3 disk, which has 12000IOPS. Looking at the monitoring metrics, nothing suggests that the database is under load. However, I have tried upgrading the database instance to db.m6g.2xlarge, but that had no impact on the "cold" (first) run of this query.
This query will not see much benefit of query caches. There is a "long tail" of combination of ids that the application will use.
This question is related to https://serverfault.com/questions/1165336/how-do-i-use-explain-to-identify-next-step-in-query-optimization?noredirect=1#comment1525463_1165336
SELECT 
    this_.sid AS id1_21_1_,
    this_.updated AS updated2_21_1_,
    this_.track_sid AS track3_21_1_,
    this_.keywordnode_sid AS keywordn4_21_1_,
    this_.status AS status5_21_1_
FROM
    keywordnode_track_test this_
WHERE
    this_.track_sid IN (154 , 1647,
        5089,
        5890,
        7515,
        7523,
        10888, [about 1500 ids more]);

Tables
CREATE TABLE `keywordnode_track_test` (
  `sid` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `keywordnode_sid` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `track_sid` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`sid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `keywordnode_track_keywordnode_FK` (`keywordnode_sid`,`track_sid`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `keywordnode_track_track_FK` (`track_sid`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `keywordnode_track_keywordnode_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`keywordnode_sid`) REFERENCES `keywordnode` (`sid`),
  CONSTRAINT `keywordnode_track_track_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`track_sid`) REFERENCES `track` (`sid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=55601145 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

What can I do do bring down the query time?

To begin with how is this list generated , if it is present in another table a join would be better ?

See Equality Range Optimization of Many-Valued Comparisons , update index statistic by running ANALYZE TABLE first.  Maybe an index (track_sid,status,keywordnode_sid,updated ) might make a slight improvement

@ErgestBasha a base query runs first with a whole range of criteria (based on user input) to fetch the list of tracks (track_sid). The base query makes a one-to-many join, and to avoid a cartesian product additional queries (like this one) is run separately to load related one-to-many data.

Try to save your long list of needed id values into the temporary indexed table and join it into your query instead of your WHERE IN.

@Akina ran that experiment now. The query took 20 seconds. I'm not sure if that is an improvement, or just a coincidence (I've seen the query times vary between 20 and 30 seconds before).

the query times vary between 20 and 30 seconds Is this clear query execution time or complete time, including sending the output to the client?

Splitting a query into two (and using ids) is likely to be slower.  See how fast the combined query is -- JOIN or EXISTS or subquery.
